# Trello API: get members, attachments, and card information in one call?

Tags: php, trello

I can get data from the Trello API using this:

```
private function get_card_info($card_id) {
    $client =         new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $base =           $this->endpoint . $card_id;
    $params =         "?key=" . $this->api_key . "&token=" . $this->token;      
    $cardURL =        $base . $params;
    $membersURL =     $base . "/members" . $params;
    $attachmentsURL = $base . "/attachments" . $params;

    $response = $client->get($cardURL);
    $this->card_info['card'] = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    $response = $client->get($membersURL);
    $this->card_info['members'] = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    $response = $client->get($attachmentsURL);      
    $this->card_info['attachments'] = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

However, this is broken into three calls.  Is there a way to get card information, the member information, and the attachment information all in one call?  The [docs](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card) mention using `&fields=name,id`, but that only seems to limit what's returned from the base call to the `cards` endpoint.

It's absurd to have to hit the API 3 times every time I need card information, but I can't find any examples gathering all that's needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trello replied to me, and stated that they would have answered much like Vladimir did.  However, the only response I got from that was the initial card data, sans attachments and members.  However, they also directed me to [this blog post](http://blog.clarkrasmussen.com/2014/10/13/batch-requests-with-the-trello-api/) that covers batching requests.  They apparently removed it from the docs because of the confusion it created.

To summarize the changes, you essentially make a call to `/batch`, and append a `urls` GET parameter with a comma separated list of endpoints to hit.  The working final version ended up looking like this:

```
private function get_card_info($card_id) {
    $client =         new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $params =         "&key=" . $this->api_key . "&token=" . $this->token;

    $cardURL = "/cards/" . $card_id;
    $members = "/cards/" . $card_id . "/members";
    $attachmentsURL = "/cards/" . $card_id . "/attachments";

    $urls = $this->endpoint . implode(',', [$cardURL, $members, $attachmentsURL]) . $params;

    $response = $client->get($urls);
    $this->card = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try hitting the API with following parameters:

`/cards/[id]?fields=name,idList&members=true&member_fields=all&& attachments=true&&attachment_fields=all`

Comment: I'll check this as soon as I get home to my personal laptop.  Is this in the docs anywhere?